# Fatal Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::prepare()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

As I'm tryint to put the contents of my array into a database I've stumbled upon an error. I'm still a PHP scrub and maybe the error is obvious but I cannot seem to find my fix.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $connection = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO items (ItemName) VALUES (ItemName)");
    $connection->execute(array('ItemName' => $item));
}
?>
```

Comment: `$connection` has been defined somewhere?

Comment: looks like $connection isn't a PDO Object, but a PDOStatement "already". Where did you define that?

Comment: it's a typo; you missed the colon in values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, `$connection` isn't what you think, it should be. As the error tolds you, `$connection` is an `PDOStatement` instead of `PDO` and `PDOStatement` hasn't a `prepare` method.

This happens, because in every loop (except the first one), you overwrite `$connection` with the result of `prepare` (That's an `PDOStatement`!)

Given, before the loop `$connection` is a `PDO` object, you should just change the code inside the loop to something like this

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $query = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO items (ItemName) VALUES (:ItemName)");
    $query->execute(array(':ItemName' => $item));
}
```